# Unturned not opening on Apple Mac

Tags: technical-issues, unturned

I was on Steam one day, and opened Unturned after a recent update. When I opened it, it bounced around on the dock for a bit, then disappeared. It seems to be an error with Mac only, as Windows players don't *seem* to be experiencing this, like me.
I play on an Apple Mac, Version: Yosemite 10.10.5
I would appreciate any help with this.
***EDIT: Answer below.***

Comment: Answers don't belong as part of the question.  As you just answered it, that's all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your system when there are any updates and then re-install Steam to fix most issues like this.

Answer (score -1):

Reinstall on steam. If this doesn't work:
Try finding the old update somewhere (trusted) online and rolling back.
Because sometimes it be like that.

It may be worth dropping an e-mail to the developers too.